# for loop linux scripting: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Tags: linux

I'm at the very beginning in scripting. ( I have just finished Linux LPI essentials)
I have the following challenge:

Create a new group. Each group must have a unique name. The script must check to ensure that no duplicate group names exist on the system. If a duplicate is found, an error needs to be reported, and the administrator must try another group name.

Here is my "script":

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

echo "Please enter a group name"                                                
read gname                                                                      

for $gname in /etc/group; do                                                    
echo "Please enter another group name"                                          
read gname                                                                      
done                                                                            

groupadd $gname                                                                 
echo "Group $gname has been created"
```

this is the error I received.

```
Please enter a group name                                                       
alexandru                                                                       
test.sh: 6: test.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I DID IT!!!
Thank you Guys!!! ( Kalpa Welivitigoda and Rawkode )

## !/bin/bash

echo "Please enter a group name"
read gname
groupadd $gname
while [ $? != 0 ];
do
echo "Enter a new group name"
read gname
groupadd $gname
done

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to parse `/etc/group`, instead - rely on `groupadd` to perform it's job correctly.

When you use `groupadd` and the name the group already exists, it will exit with a non-zero code.

`if [[ $? != 0 ]];
then
    echo "Error, group already exists"
fi`

So to loop this until you get a correct group:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Enter group name: "
read group

until groupadd $group
do
  read group
done

echo "${group} created"
```

Comment: Rawkode thank you so much for the hint ! ( you are awsome ) here is my script : !/bin/bash echo "Please enter a group name"                                       
read gname       
groupadd $gname                                           
if [ $? != 0 ];                                                                 
then                                                                            
echo "Error the group allready exists"                                          
fi                           
it works great but it should ask me again another name and try that one as well

Comment: I have added a sample loop for you

Comment: @EduardPetru You should probably mark this answer as correct, based on your solution. Thanks

Comment: how can I do that ? ( sorry I am new and I do not know how )

Answer (score 0):

You probably run it with sh, not bash. Try bash fileName.sh, or ./fileName.sh if it's executable, but not sh fileName.sh.

Answer (score -2):

You may need to iterate over the content of `/etc/group`, try the following,

`for $gname in $(cat /etc/group); do`

On a different note, it is better to check whether the new group name also is an existing group name.

Comment: thank you for the answer! Unfortunately I still receive the same error

Comment: By bad, sorry, it should be,

`for gname in $(cat /etc/group); do`

Note that "$" is not needed in the `for`

Comment: now it gives me the following output: Please enter a group name                                                       
root                                                                            
Please enter another group name                                                 
Please enter another group name - many times ( ithink it checks each line and gives me this output as my variable would be a letter)

Comment: and I have done a cat to my file and it is not such a big one it has about 20 lines

Comment: You can use a `if` to check whether the entered groupname is there in `/etc/group`

Comment: Thank you Kalpa - please see Rawkode comment for using exitcodes - big help!